# SSRS conditional statement

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements

The logic is, If the type field is equal to 9, then the description field should be equal to Accounts. The 9 is present on the report, but the account description is not pulling. So I am trying to hard code the type 9 will always be accounts.

Comment: Sorry can you be a little more clear?  You don't really ask a question or give any information that can help us understand the issue.  Could you post a sample of your data, your report, some additional details, and possibly what attempts you've made so far?

Comment: Show the expression you are currently using, perhaps something is wrong with it.

Comment: What will the description field be for other types?